# Open source rooms/property booking engine for ASP.Net

Tags: open-source, c#, cms, reservation

We are looking for an open source solution similar to [Drupal Rooms](https://www.drupal.org/project/rooms) which is a Drupal 7 booking and room management solution for hotels and other accommodations and written in PHP.

Is there any alternative to this but developed in ASP.Net MVC or Web Forms or through another ASP.Net CMS?